# ES6 yield : what happens to the arguments of the first call next()?

Tags: ecmascript-harmony

Consider this snippet of code :

```
function foo(a) {
  console.log("Mul =", a);
  return a * 2;
};

function * process(start) {
  // next() #1
  var result = start;

  console.log("Pre-processing =", result);
  result = yield foo(result);
  // next() #2
  console.log("Process result 1 =", result);
  result = yield foo(result);
  // next() #3
  console.log("Process result 2 =", result);
  result = yield foo(result);
  // next() #4
  console.log("Process result 3 =", result);

  return foo(result);
}

var it = process(1);
console.log("#1");
console.log("Next 1 =", /*#1*/it.next("bar"));
console.log("#2");
console.log("Next 2 =", /*#2*/it.next(3));
console.log("#3");
console.log("Next 3 =", /*#3*/it.next(7));
console.log("#4");
console.log("Next 4 =", /*#4*/it.next(15));
```

And the output

```
#1
Pre-processing = 1
Mul = 1
Next 1 = { value: 2, done: false }
#2
Process result 1 = 3
Mul = 3
Next 2 = { value: 6, done: false }
#3
Process result 2 = 7
Mul = 7
Next 3 = { value: 14, done: false }
#4
Process result 3 = 15
Mul = 15
Next 4 = { value: 30, done: true }
```

Why is the first call to `it.next()` skip arguments (in the code above, `"bar"`) altogether? Or, in other words, why is the behavior different in subsequent calls? I would've expected calling the generator function would skip arguments, and that the call to `next()` would actually initialize the iterator, making the process more coherent, no?

Comment: **I would've expected calling the generator function would skip arguments** If so you wouldn't be able to pass several arguments. `next` seems to only take into account the first argument it's passed. For this reason, the arguments for the iterator will be those passed to the generator. As a result, there is no way to get the optional argument of the first `next`. Those are all guesses though.

Comment: You got a point there. However, if [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FNew_in_JavaScript%2F1.7#Destructuring_assignment) are ever officialized, this could solve that. Ex: `var [a, b] = yield c;` would receive the arguments from `it.next(1, 2);`.

Comment: This actually doesn't change anything, you wouldn't need destructuration. Destructuration would only work if yield "returns" an array. In this case, you could also save that array in one variable. Also, my point was that to be able to have the arguments of the first `next` be taken into account, you'd need some place to get them (no previous `yield` to "return" them), or they should be cast into the generator's arguments. The fact is, it would be illogical because `next` handles only 1 argument atm. But really, it could change.

Comment: That could be an answer and I would upvote it.

Comment: your example is obscenely complex, and you don't actually say whether or not you're using ECMAScript-harmony or JS 1.8. Title and tags don't match.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, the tags says "ecmascript-harmony", and I have seen many examples that were "simple", but could not help me understand how generators worked; most of them using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and not a pure JS example.

Comment: @YanickRochon I asked a [duplicate question with a substantially simpler example, see if it makes more sense to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271216/in-es6-what-happens-to-the-arguments-in-the-first-call-to-an-iterators-next?noredirect=1#comment32066572_21271216).

Comment: ECMAScript-Harmony isn't Javascript. Javascript has its own spec'd, and implimented versions of generators which don't require `function *` even. Javascript is a superset of ECMAScript and when ECMAScript is playing catch up the differentiation is required.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, I'm sorry, I don't see the point of that comment. No offense, seriously, but my example and tag are clearly indicating ECMAScript harmony *and* my example is using the ECMAScript definition of the generator function. Why even making references to the JS 1.8 specs at all? As for your question, it is the same as mine :) But I think I'd rather like the answer here as it contains more details on the subject. My example was, perhaps, overly complicated, but demonstrated clearly the problem regardless.

Comment: As for the edit. The precision might have not been necessary. The question applies to both JS and ECMA specs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In the draft:**

After some more research, the answer lies within harmony's draft (see the wiki: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators#methodnext).

`next` is supposed to have no argument. However, it seems calling `next` with one argument is just equivalent to call `send` with one argument. Here lies the answer. `send` is designed to throw an error if called first (no `next` prior).

So basically, you should not be able to "initialize" your iterator by passing an argument to `next` cause you're not authorized to do so.

**In the implementations:**

However, this is just the specification. To summarize what's been said as comments, there are at least 2 reasons why you can't pass an argument to your first `next` and have to pass it to your generator.

The first one would be the fact that you would need some method to actually get this argument. You cannot do it the same way you'd do it with your next calls `let myVar = yield myValue`.
The second one would be that `next` only accepts one argument and that is quite limiting, whereas you can pass an infinite amount of arguments to your generator when producing the iterator.

However, this is only what's happening at the moment. Nothing says that the draft or implementations won't change. We could certainly imagine `send` accepting any number of arguments (no reason but hey, who knows), and being able to cast it into the generator's arguments. Or whatever.

Comment: `it seems calling next with one argument is just equivalent to call send with one argument`  --   

Is there any reference for this statement? I did not found it in the draft.     
Thank you!

Comment: I got it. `send` method has been eliminated and replaced by an argument to the `next` method   https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1555

Comment: @zhiyelee it's been a while and things have evolved since then, but I guess this statement of mine was based on the implementations of generators at that time (chrome, ff), and maybe on something that was written on one of mozilla's page, can't tell you much more (and I guess it doesn't matter much anymore :)).