# Where argument of first next() call goes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-6

I have a simple generator function

```
function *generate(arg) {
  console.log(arg)
  for(let i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
    console.log(yield i);
  }
}
```

Then I init the generator and trying to print values in console:

```
var gen = generate('arg'); //doesn't print
gen.next('a'); // prints 'arg'
gen.next('b'); // prints 'b'
gen.next('c'); // prints 'c'
// ... nothing surprising later
```

Where did argument `a` from first `next()` call go? Is there a way to utilize it inside generator function?

Here is a [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20*generate(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(arg)%0A%20%20for(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%203%3Bi%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(yield%20i)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20gen%20%3D%20generate('arg')%3B%0Agen.next('a')%3B%0Agen.next('b')%3B%0Agen.next('c')%3B) where you can see that result.

Comment: The first `next` starts the generator’s execution. You can’t use the value you pass to it; it’s thrown out. You also weren’t allowed to pass anything but `undefined` to make this clear, but that’s probably changed since you’re not getting a TypeError: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators (see If state = “newborn” under Internal method: send).

Comment: Well, if in a draft version it was designed to throw an error, it makes me sure, that this argument should not be accessible to generator. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @minitech: I believe they are discussing a way of how to access the argument of the first call in ES7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `next` method is defined as follows:

> [**25.3.1.2 Generator.prototype.next ( value )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generator.prototype.next)
>
> The `next` method performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Let *g* be the **this** value.
> 2. Return [GeneratorResume](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorresume)(*g*, *value*).

The GeneratorResume abstract operation uses *value* at step 10:

> [**25.3.3.3 GeneratorResume ( generator, value )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorresume)
>
> The abstract operation GeneratorResume with arguments generator and
>   value performs the following steps:
>
> 5. Let *genContext* be the value of *generator*’s [[GeneratorContext]] [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots).
>
> 10. Resume the [suspended](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts) evaluation of *genContext* using [NormalCompletion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-normalcompletion)(*value*) as the result of the operation that
>       [suspended](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts) it. Let *result* be the value returned by the resumed
>       computation.

The first possibility is that the evaluations was suspended by the use of `yield` (i.e. `"suspendedYield"` state).

Its behavior is explained in [14.4.14 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generator-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> *YieldExpression* : `yield`
>
> 1. Return [GeneratorYield](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatoryield)([CreateIterResultObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createiterresultobject)(**undefined**,
>      **false**)).

(Analogous for *YieldExpression* : `yield` *AssignmentExpression*)

The [GeneratorYield](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatoryield) abstract operation suspends the generator as follows:

> 7. Set the code evaluation state of *genContext* such that when evaluation is resumed with a [Completion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-completion-record-specification-type) *resumptionValue* the
>      following steps will be performed:
>
>    1. Return *resumptionValue*.
>    2. NOTE: This returns to the evaluation of the *YieldExpression* production that originally called this abstract operation.

So the value passed as the argument of the second `next` is used as the returned value of the first `yield` expression. And the value passed as the argument of the 3rd `next` is used as the returned value of the 2nd `yield` expression. And so on.

However, there is also the possibility that the generator hadn't started yet (i.e. `"suspendedStart"` state).

This is done by the [GeneratorStart](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorstart) abstract operation:

> 4. Set the code evaluation state of *genContext* such that when evaluation is resumed for that [execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts) the following
>      steps will be performed:

But those "following steps" don't use the resumption value.

Therefore, the value passed as the argument of the first `next` is discarded.

Comment: However, there's a proposal to add a new meta property to make it available.

Comment: @Bergi Interesting. Can you link that proposal?

Comment: I guess it was [this one](https://github.com/allenwb/ESideas/blob/master/Generator%20metaproperty.md). There was also an accompanying thread on es-discuss but I can't find it right now

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't use that first value.  It's instructive if you change your code to :

```
'use strict';
function *generate(arg) {
  console.log(arg)
  for(let i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
    console.log(yield i);
  }
  return 'done';
}

var gen = generate('arg');
console.log(gen.next('a'));
console.log(gen.next('b'));
console.log(gen.next('c'));
console.log(gen.next('d'));
```

When you instantiate the generator, it does not start executing yet and nothing is logged.  On the first `gen.next('a')`, you run up to the first yield which goes through the `console.log(arg)` in the generator and then does `yield 0`. This then gets `console.log` in the caller and you get `{value: 0, done:false}`, etc. until you complete the iteration.  The overall output looks as follows:

```
arg
{ value: 0, done: false }
b
{ value: 1, done: false }
c
{ value: 2, done: false }
d
{ value: 'done', done: true }
```

The final `done` is the return value and will be `undefined` if you omit the `return` on the generator.

Comment: Actually this is not a question about what's going after `next`. The question was about first argument and where it is used. @minitech♦ gave the correct answer – nowhere, it was designed to dissappear