# Does it ever make sense to include a value in the first next call to generator iterator?

Tags: javascript, generator

As the question states, does it ever make sense to pass a value to the first `iterator.next()` call or will it always be ignored? As an example:

```js
function* foo(x) {
  var y = 2 * (yield(x + 1));
  var z = yield(y / 3);
  return (x + y + z);
}

var it = foo(5);

// note: not sending anything into `next()` here
console.log(it.next()); // { value:6, done:false }
console.log(it.next(12)); // { value:8, done:false }
console.log(it.next(13)); // { value:42, done:true }
```

Notice there is not a value being passed to the first `next()`. However, in the article I'm trying to learn from, it goes on to say:

> But if we did pass in a value to that first next(..) call, nothing bad would happen. It would just be a tossed-away value

Okay. That makes sense. But now I'm curious to know if there is a use case (or if it's even possible to utilize) where passing in a value has a benefit.

**Article: https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators**

Comment: The argument passed in the *next* call replaces the value returned by the previous *yield* expression. Since on the first call there is no previous *yield*, there's nothing to replace so there doesn't seem to be any use case for including it.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it always be ignored?

[Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32446723/1048572)

> Is a use case where passing in a value has a benefit?

When it simplifies the rest of your code. In your example, that could be using a loop instead of writing it out:

```
const it = foo(5);
for (let i=11; i<=13; i++)
    console.log(it.next(i));
```

Now we're passing `11` into the first call to `.next` even if there's no use for the value anywhere.