# JS Generators: How is `return yield` different from `yield`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

```
function* foo() {
  yield 123
};

// - - -

function* foo() {
  return yield 123
};
```

I can’t seem to demonstrate the difference between the two.

- Is there a demonstrable difference?
- Should `return` be used in a generator?

Comment: thanks for ask, many answer help me to know more about JS Generators.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First, I'll start by saying that Generators are a somewhat complicated topic, so giving a complete overview here won't be possible. For more information I'd highly recommend Kyle Simpson's [*You Don't Know JS*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) series. Book 5 (Async & Performance) has an excellent discussion on the ins and outs of generators.

Onto the specific example you gave though!

First, the code that you wrote in the example will show *no difference* but *only if* it's run correctly. Here's an example:

```
function* foo() {
  yield 123;
}

function* bar() {
  return yield 123;
}

var f = foo();
var b = bar();

f.next(); // {value: 123, done: false}
f.next(); // {value: undefined, done: true}
b.next(); // {value: 123, done: false}
b.next(); // {value: undefined, done: true}
```

As you can see, I'm not calling the generator like a normal function. The generator itself returns a *generator object* (a form of iterator). We store that iterator in a variable and use the `.next()` function to advance the iterator to the next step (a `yield` or `return` keyword).

The `yield` keyword allows us to pass a value into the generator, and this is where your examples will run differently. Here's what that would look like:

```
function* foo() {
  yield 123;
}

function* bar() {
  return yield 123;
}

var f = foo();
var b = bar();

// Start the generator and advance to the first `yield`
f.next(); // {value: 123, done: false}
b.next(); // {value: 123, done: false}

/** Now that I'm at a `yield` statement I can pass a value into the `yield`
 * keyword. There aren't any more `yield` statements in either function,
 * so .next() will look for a return statement or return undefined if one
 * doesn't exist. Like so:
 */
f.next(2); // {value: undefined, done: true}
b.next(2); // {value: 2, done: true}
```

*Notice that `f.next(2)` will return `undefined` as a value, whereas `b.next(2)` returns the number 2.*

This is because the value we're passing into the second `.next()` call is [sent into the to the `bar()` generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next#sending_values_to_the_generator), assigned as a result of the `yield` expression, which appears after a `return` keyword; that means the value we send into the generator is returned back to us and finishes the generator.

`foo()` has no explicit return statement, so you don't get the value back (`foo()` already yielded its only value, so the [generator is finished](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#description), and the result is `{ done:true, value: undefined` }`.

Note that iterators [don't typically consume this `return` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65871026/when-using-spread-syntax-on-a-generator-why-return-value-is-not-retrieved), even though this answer demonstrates how you could manually get the return value using `.next()`

Hope that this helps!

Comment: There is some small logical flaws in the writing: `bar()` does not return `2`. It returns a `Generator` object (as you already pointed out above). However, the final `b.next(2)` call returns an object with its `value` prop set to `2`. That is because, when calling `next()` after the final `yield` (i.e. the final pause/interruption), it runs the function to completion, and its final `value` is the function's return value.

Comment: Nice example thanks :) I incorporated the feedback from @Domi and added a few more links to explain how the **second** `.next()` call passes values *into* the generator, which are substituted into the code, as if replacing the `yield`, as code resumes from the point of `yield`... (not the **first** `.next()` call; that value is ignored, as mentioned in comments to the accepted answer, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21271216/1175496), and [mentioned here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next#sect1)

Answer (score 20):

The difference is the result value of the last continuation call:

```
function* fooA() {
  yield 123
};
var a = fooA();
console.log(a.next(1)); // {done:false, value:123}
console.log(a.next(2)); // {done:true,  value:undefined}

function* fooB() {
  return 40 + (yield 123)
};
var b = fooB();
console.log(b.next(1)); // {done:false, value:123}
console.log(b.next(2)); // {done:true,  value:42}
```

Most generators don't need a `return` value, their purpose is the generation of a value stream as a side effect when they are running. All iterators are of this kind, if they are ran by a `for of` loop the result just signifies the end, but the value is discarded.

However, there also are generators where a result value is important, e.g. when they are used as a tool to describe asynchronous processes (in a polyfill for `async`/`await` promise syntax, or also many more things like CSP). You also get the `return`ed value when using `yield*` on an iterable.

In any case, `return yield` together doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: Hmmph... Just can't understand why it finally yields 42, not 41, so is that the `yield` excuted two times?

Comment: @a_a The argument to the first `.next(1)` call [is discarded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21271216/1048572). The final result comes from adding `40` and `2`.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: Great answer thank you. You say "`return yield` together doesn't sound very useful", I found this SO question while searching for the [Observable technique to pause a generator](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/pause-a-generator). I know ["Observable is not JS"](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observable-javascript), but this answer's still useful! Also even in vanilla JS generators, a `return` statement is implied when omitted. So [`return yield` might be a useful pattern](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance/ch4.md#tale-of-two-questions)

Comment: @TheRedPea In the former example, it seems it's used to the same effect as `yield …; return`, ensuring to yield at least a single value before pausing. In the latter example, `yield` seems to have been (ab)used to mean `await`, which is unnecessary before `return` in case of implicitly-unwrapping promises, but can occasionally be helpful for clarity or type correctness.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see what you mean if "in the first example" you're referring [to this](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/pause-a-generator), you say it's like `yield …; return`, but I think that's not exactly true; but I think I see what you mean (how the `return` statement is not really necessary), which [I explored here](https://observablehq.com/d/fc776cb054d112f7)

Comment: @TheRedPea Yes, had I expected you to take me literally I would have written `if (paused) { yield i; return; }`