# When using spread syntax on a generator why return value is not retrieved

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, generator, spread-syntax

I was expecting 4 to be part of the sequence array, so why is it skipped?

```js
function* generate() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  return 4
}
let sequence = [...generate()];
console.log(sequence); // 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: @MisterJojo there is, but it  finishes the generator.

Comment: @MisterJojo the return statement is marking the generator end with the attribute `done:true`

Comment: When not using return and chaining next() calls, you get an undefined last value

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha you do not get the `undefined` when iterating though and it is the same with `return`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli yes but you get one element in the done:true object with return

Comment: I guess the spread operator doesn't expect a value in the done:true object

Comment: yes all of the iterators do not use the `done:true`. `for (x of genarator())` will also not get it.

Comment: I just ran the snippet. Calling next method on the generator shows that when value is 4, then done is true. However, when destructing the generator to an array, it skips the last value. In this case, changing the last statement from `return` to `yield` actually solves this issue. The reason it looks like is because the destructing is actually checking for the value of `done` and when it's false, it stops destructing and hence, misses the last value. Changing to `yield` does not return `done: true` on next and this seems to me the reason for skipping the last value.

Comment: The `done` flag is checked in a way that ignores the `value` returned. When `done` is `true`, iteration is complete.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators
"**Done**: This is true if the last value in the sequence **has already been consumed**."

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it makes sense, also read on the documentation: > After a terminating value has been yielded additional calls to next() should continue to return {done: true}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` value of a generator function is not considered part of the sequence. It is returned from the last `.next()` call as `{done: true, value:…}`, where `done: true` implies that the sequence was completed and `.next()` should not be called again.

Why is that so, why couldn't we just yield the last value with the `done` flag set to `true`? Because then we could not represent an *empty* sequence with an iterator - the first `.next()` call would already lead to at least one value.<sup>1</sup>

So usually, generator functions do not return anything (but `undefined`), and all sequence values are yielded with the same syntax - there is no weird special syntax for the last value<sup>2</sup>:

```
function* generate() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
}
```

<sub>1: Other languages do this differently. There, iterators have a separate `.hasNext()` method that is called *before* `.next()`, or their `.next()` method either returns a value or throws a `StopIteration` exception. They don't have any "final value".

2: Having to know beforehand that a value is that last and using `return` instead of
`yield` for it would make the logic for dynamically generated sequences much more complicated.</sub>

Comment: This happens if you combine a function that must return a value with an ambiguous computation (e.g. `[]`). You are stuck with a meaningless return value. The iterator protocol has no formal foundation. It is poorly designed and ignores decades of CS.

Comment: Best part of the answer is explaining why this approach allows us to represent an empty sequence, as opposed to the alternative that the question implies. Also in response to your footnote, you can think of `next()` as a sort of [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) where `done` is `!has_value`.

Comment: @scriptum I understand the `IteratorResult` type to be a poor man's `Maybe` for the usual iterator use case - you either have `{done: false, value: …}` or `{done: true}`. Also, generator functions additionally serve as coroutines in JS, and for them the final value is rather useful.