# ES6 generators mechanism - first value passed to next() goes where?

Tags: javascript, generator, yield

When passing parameters to `next()` of ES6 generators, why is the first value ignored? More concretely, why does the output of this say `x = 44` instead of `x = 43`:

```
function* foo() {
    let i = 0;
    var x = 1 + (yield "foo" + (++i));
    console.log(`x = ${x}`);
}

fooer = foo();

console.log(fooer.next(42));
console.log(fooer.next(43));

// output:
// { value: 'foo1', done: false }
// x = 44
// { value: undefined, done: true }
```

My mental model for the behavior of such a generator was something like:

1. return `foo1` and pause at yield (and the `next` call which returns `foo1` takes as argument `42`)
2. pause until next call to `next`
3. on next yield proceed to the line with `var x = 1 + 42` because this was the argument previously received
4. print `x = 43`
5. just return a `{done: true}` from the last `next`, ignoring its argument (`43`) and stop.

Now, obviously, this is not what's happening. So... **what am I getting wrong here?**

Comment: Calling `foo()` does not execute until the first `yield`, it only creates the generator object. The first `next()` call starts execution from the top of the function till the first `yield` - and returns the value yielded there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In ES6, what happens to the arguments in the first call to an iterator's `next` method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21271216/1048572)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up writing this kind of code to investigate the behavior more thoroughly (after re-re-...-reading the [MDN docs on generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)):

```
function* bar() {
    pp('in bar');
    console.log(`1. ${yield 100}`);
    console.log(`after 1`);
    console.log(`2. ${yield 200}`);
    console.log(`after 2`);
}
let barer = bar();
pp(`1. next:`, barer.next(1));
pp(`--- done with 1 next(1)\n`);
pp(`2. next:`, barer.next(2));
pp(`--- done with 2 next(2)\n`);
pp(`3. next:`, barer.next(3));
pp(`--- done with 3 next(3)\n`);
```

which outputs this:

```
in bar
1. next: { value: 100, done: false }
--- done with 1 next(1)

1. 2
after 1
2. next: { value: 200, done: false }
--- done with 2 next(2)

2. 3
after 2
3. next: { value: undefined, done: true }
--- done with 3 next(3)
```

So apparently the correct mental model would be like this:

- on first call to `next`, the generator function body is run up to the `yield` expression, the "argument" of `yield` (`100` the first time) is returned as the value returned by `next`, and the generator body is **paused *before* evaluating the value of the yield expression** -- the *"before"* part is crucial
- only on the second call to `next` is the value of the *first* `yield` expression computed/replaced with the value of the argument given to next on **this** call (not with the one given in the *previous* one as I expected), and execution runs until the second `yield`, and `next` returns the value of the argument of this second yield -- **here was my mistake:** I assumed the value of the *first `yield` expression* is the argument of the *first call to `next`*, but it's actually the argument of *the second call to `next`*, or, another way to put it, it's **the argument of the call to `next` during whose execution the value is actually computed**

This probably made more sense to who invented this because the # of calls to `next` is one more times the number of `yield` statements (there's also the last one returning `{ value: undefined, done: true }` to signal termination), so if the argument of the first call would not have been ignored, then the one of the last call would have had to be ignored. Also, while evaluating the body of next, the substitution would have started with the argument of its *previous* invocation. This *would have been much more intuitive imho*, but I assume it's about following the convention for generators in other languages too and consistency is the best thing in the end...

---

**Off-topic but enlightening:** Just tried to do the same exploration in Python, which apparently implements generators similar to Javascript, I immediately got a `TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator` when trying to pass an argument to the first call to `next()` (clear signal that my mental model was wrong!), and the iterator API also ends by throwing a `StopIteration` exception, so no "extra" `next()` needed just to check if the `done` is true (I imagine using this extra call for side effects that utilize the last next argument would only result in *very* hard to understand and debug code...). Much easier to "grok it" than in JS...

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Taking the argument from the previous `next` call makes no sense, that's as if it was buffered. It would not allow to immediately "respond" to the passed value.

Comment: Given that generators implement passing "messages" back and forth (or in and out), one always needs to start somewhere. I guess it would also have been possible to have one more `yield` statement than `next` calls, by having the first yielded value go nowhere, but that's just ugly in the more common case.

Comment: @Bergi ah, that makes sense, I didn't think at all in terms of "responsiveness"... guess that the "possible reaction to the value of an argument passed to `next`" **is** intuitive to happen during that *actual* call to next if I think of it this way! ...but throwing an error when passing an argument to first call to `next`, like Python I see does, would help newbs like me a loooot :)

Answer (score 4):

I got this from [Axel Rauschmayer's Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_generators.html#sec_generators-as-observers), especially 22.4.1.1.

On receiving a `.next(arg)`, the first action of a generator is to feed `arg` to `yield`. But on the first call to `.next()`, there is no `yield` to receive this, since it is only at the end of the execution.

Only on the second invocation `x = 1 + 43` is executed and subsequently logged, and the generator ends.

Comment: That explanation is... interesting. I think I got it in the end by myself, see answer, neither your explanation nor the docs seem explicit enough to me: what does "feed `arg` to `yield`" or "no `yield` to receive this" even mean?! I think of code in terms of a formal model of evaluation and the "substitution model" (https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node10.html) is the simplest for me to understand, not in terms of "feeding", "sending", "receiving" etc. ...these words don't make much sense to me unless I'm talking about multiple processes...

Answer (score 2):

Also had a hard time wrapping my head around generators, especially when throwing in if-statements depended on yielded values. Nevertheless, the if-statement was actually what helped me getting it at last:

```js
function* foo() {
  const firstYield = yield 1
  console.log('foo', firstYield)

  const secondYield = yield 3
  console.log('foo', secondYield)

  if (firstYield === 2) {
    yield 5
  }
}

const generator = foo()

console.log('next', generator.next( /* Input skipped */ ).value)
console.log('next', generator.next(2).value)
console.log('next', generator.next(4).value)

/* 
  Outputs:

  next 1
  foo 2
  next 3
  foo 4
  next 5    
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything immediately became clear once I made this realization.

Here's your typical generator:

```
function* f() {
  let a = yield 1;
  // a === 200
  let b = yield 2;
  // b === 300
}

let gen = f();
gen.next(100) // === { value: 1, done: false }
gen.next(200) // === { value: 2, done: false }
gen.next(300) // === { value: undefined, done: true }
```

But here's what actually happens. **The only way to make generator execute anything is to call `next()` on it.** Therefore there needs to be a way for a generator to execute code that comes before the first yield.

```
function* f() {
  // All generators implicitly start with that line
  // v--------<---< 100
       = yield
  // ^-------- your first next call jumps right here

  let a = yield 1;
  // a === 200
  let b = yield 2;
  // b === 300
}
```